# Remove all contents of an openldap server in Centos

Tags: centos, openldap

I'm facing a problem and I don't know how to solve it. In fact, I have done some ldapadd and I've realised that I need to delete all things from the server. So what I've tested is to reinstall yum but it doesn't solve my problem because the contents remains even if  openldap-servers is removed. I know that with ldapdelete I can delete entries one by one but I was hoping for something like dpkg-reconfigure. So how can I solve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need to delete the whole LDAP tree with all records - you can just delete all files in /var/lib/ldap/*. The path could be distro related.

You can check the current path with

```
# grep ^directory /etc/openldap/slapd.conf
/var/lib/ldap
```